PHP - Syntax to append a string value to function argument?
I'm using the prepared_query and prepared_select functions from PHPdelusions (https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/prepared_select)
The standard functions are fine on known data sets, where you can hard-code the number of variables and their names:
function prepared_query($mysqli, $sql, $params, $types = "")
{
  $types = $types ?: str_repeat("s", count($params));
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
  $stmt->execute();
  return $stmt;
}

function prepared_select($mysqli, $sql, $params = [], $types = "") {
  return prepared_query($mysqli, $sql, $params, $types)->get_result();
}

In a usual case, this would work fine:
$result = prepared_select($conn, $strsql, [$cat_code, $cat_code, $cat_code]

(I've not included the actual query as I don't think it's relevant, but can if required).
However, I have a query that builds in a random fashion depending upon user input, so the final argument of the function will gradually expand.
I assumed this would be as simple as putting all the string names, comma separated into a string (called $combined_string for simplicity), then using [$combined_string] as the final argument. e.g.:
$combined_string = "$cat_code, $cat_code, $cat_code, $next_variable";

However the function appears to treat this as a single string, rather than using the values of the 4 strings within, and throws:
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: The number of elements in the type definition string must match the number of bind variables 

What syntax would be required to use the strings within the combined string in a function argument?

Why do you think it should be a string? Why not [$cat_code, $cat_code, $cat_code, $next_variable]?

@Barmar - I don't know how many extra variables there are going to be or what their names are.

Then how do you know how many variables should be in the string? If you're constructing the string dynamically, you can do the same with the array.

I can't work out the syntax to append variables to the argument though?
